# Python installed on a shared folder

Tags: python, windows

I installed a python on my Windows and shared it using Windows builtin sharing function. Then I launch visual studio code on another system and select that python as interpreter to run a simple print("1") but it shows timeout waiting debuggee to spawn. Is there a way to solve this issue?
Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFPiV.png)

Windows 10
Python 3.11

Comment: @starball Hi! I cant add it as image cuz I don't have enough reputation points lol

Comment: Read my comment carefully :) I am not asking you to add it as an image.